# Will this go in an infinite loop?

Tags: java, static

I am starting in java, so please bear with me if this sounds stupid.

I am trying the below code:

**First.java**

```
class First {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        First f = new First();
        f.print();
    }

    private void print() {
        System.out.println( "Hello, World!" );
    }
}
```

Within the `main` function, i re-instantiate the same class as i need to call a non-static method from within the static main method.

While this works, i am wondering is this a good way to do it? And how many instances of `f` are created.

How can i make sure `f` would be a `singleton`.

Thanks

Comment: Downvoting it is fine, but at least point my mistake, so i know what am i doing wrong

Comment: This will work for running a program, but isn't related to the Singleton design pattern.

Comment: this will work fine and one instance of f is created.

Comment: am removing the tag..

Comment: @web-nomad: just want to point that "re-instantiate the same class as", here its the very first instance of First and not instantiated again. I would also suggest you to know more about a class instance in context of a jvm to understand more about singleton. To know how many instances you have created for 'class First' just count the 'new First();'. The new keyword in java does this for you.

Comment: We had the very same question in our java seminars. The thing here is that the main method is static. That means it is not a method of your instantiated object but of your class and is only called once on startup by the jvm (unless you want to call it manually). On startup you only have one object of First.

Comment: Don't downvote the question. ALthough it's JAVA 101 (or even OO 101), it helps other beginners. See this Q&A for clarification: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255723/i-asked-a-really-really-stupid-question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About the first question: Only one instance of the class `First` is created.

About the second question:
The singleton pattern involves using a private constructor and a factory method. You cannot create a new instance of `First` without using the `getInstance` factory method, and all calls to `getInstance` will return the same instance.

```
class First {

    private static First instance = null;
    private First() {}

    public static First getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new First();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}

class Second {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        First f = First.getInstance(); //Always the same instance of First.
    }
}
```